# React element is not rendering / React Setup Issue

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn to react, after spending two days on setting up webpack and babel. Finally, I am trying to run some sample code. I am trying to print some strings from my react element, and unable to get this element working.

I do get the "Hello World" which is from the HTML, and no compilation errors for react, so I can validate client-server setup is working well.

However, the react element is not rendered.

Following is three file setup.

components/homepage.js

```
"use strict";

var React = require('react');

var Home = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        return (
        <div className="jumbotron">
            <h1>PluralSight Adminstrator</h1>
            <p>React, React Router, and Flux for ultra responsive website</p>
        </div>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Home;
```

And index.js

```
const jquery = $ = require('jquery');
const Home = require('./components/homepage');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

And index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    Hello World.:)
</body>
</html>
```

webpack.config.dev.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    debug: true,
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    noInfo: false,
    entry: [
        'eventsource-polyfill', // necessary for hot reloading with IE
        'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true', //note that it reloads the page if hot module reloading fails.
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/index')
    ],
    target: 'web',
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist', // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
            {test: /(\.css)$/, loaders: ['style', 'css']},
            {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
            {test: /\.(woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'url?prefix=font/&limit=5000'},
            {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
            {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: I'd recommend following a more recent tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should work (replace the home component code):

```
var Home = class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <div className="jumbotron">
            <h1>PluralSight Adminstrator</h1>
            <p>React, React Router, and Flux for ultra responsive website</p>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
```

According to [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html), if you want to use `create-react-class` then you need to install the package using NPM and require it as shown below:

```
var createReactClass = require('create-react-class');
```

The compiler might not show the error, but your browser's console must be showing some error.

Ref fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/194263/